# Setting the alpha value of an object

Tags: python

I have a few objects on the scene, each having a different colour, with an alpha value of 0.5. I would like to select one of the objects without changing the colour and only changing the alpha to 1. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure. Code? Version of blender? Research? Shader setup? Principled shader? 2.?

Comment: I only want to change the 0.5 to 1 ..bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (0.30748, 0.8, 0.274145, 0.5)

Comment: You seem to have figured it out. Change the 0.5 to 1 and run the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set the last value to 1:

```
bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (0.30748, 0.8, 0.274145, 1)
```